# Submitting checked radio buttons to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a form of radio buttons, something like :

```
   <dl>  
        <dt><label for="a1">Meatballs?</label></dt>
        <dd>
        <input type="radio" value="yes"  name="A_1">
        </dd>
        <dd>
        <input type="radio" value="no"  name="A_1">
        </dd>
        <dd>
        <input type="radio" value="maybe"  name="A_1">
        </dd>                               
    </dl>

  ... 

<dl>  
    <dt><label for="b3">Coffee?</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="yes"  name="B_3">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="no"  name="B_3">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="maybe"  name="B_3">
    </dd>                               
</dl>
<dl>  
    <dt><label for="b4">Tea?</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="yes"  name="B_4">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="no"  name="B_4">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="maybe"  name="B_4">
    </dd>                               
</dl>
```

I want to insert thise into a database with a structure like :

```
INSERT INTO `notes` ( `group`, `data` ) VALUES ...
```

I am setting some of these values in the processing php like:

```
$b = "Choices";

// these would be the groups
$bg3 = "Coffee";
$bg4 = "Tea";


// these are the data values
$bp3 = $_POST['B_3'];
$bp4 = $_POST['B_4'];

$b3 = array( $b, $bg3, $bp3 );
$b4 = array ($b, $bg4, $bp4 );
```

So in my thinking if I need to insert the group value because the 3rd choice had been selected I would have `$group = $b3[1]; $data = $b3[2]`

In my example there will be about 25 choices with one submit at the end.  I need help understanding what would be the most efficient way to loop through all of the radio buttons that are checked and `INSERT` their values where they need to go?

I need these all to be unchecked and not process unless they have a selection made.  Do I need to write insert statements for ever single one?

### Update

Thanks to the answer below I now have a more efficient way to get all of the values into an array so using dqhendricks example I can generate an array like this for each set (a,b, etc..)  :

```
print_r($b);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => [2] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => Milk [2] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => Water [2] => yes ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => Coffee [2] => ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => Tea [2] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => Beer [2] => ) [6] => Array ( [0] => Choices [1] => Wine [2] => ) )
```

This array was generated from just having the second radio button checked.

Comment: First of all, the array you posted as a result of dqhendricks code seems incomplete.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. I am changing stuff from my real code and probably making it more confusing.  I changed the example to `print_r` so it was a little more readable.

Comment: Re-Updated my answer, sorry, I forgot things (4:05 AM here) I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Merged my original solution with bqhendrick's one and refactoring your original form to clarify var names and to keep it simpler.

First of all, you should give default values (CHECKED attribute) to radio buttons in order to avoid NULLs and should name radio inputs correctly. Instead of A_1, B_1 and so on, name them like the "group" they refer. Example:

```
<dl>  
        <dt><label for="a1">Meatballs?</label></dt>
        <dd>
        <input type="radio" value="yes"  name="Meatballs">
        </dd>
        <dd>
        <input type="radio" value="no"  name="Meatballs">
        </dd>
        <dd>
        <input type="radio" value="maybe"  name="Meatballs" CHECKED>
        </dd>                               
    </dl>

  ... 

<dl>  
    <dt><label for="b3">Coffee?</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="yes"  name="Coffee">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="no"  name="Coffee">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="maybe"  name="Coffee" CHECKED>
    </dd>                               
</dl>
<dl>  
    <dt><label for="b4">Tea?</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="yes"  name="Tea">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="no"  name="Tea">
    </dd>
    <dd>
    <input type="radio" value="maybe"  name="Tea" CHECKED>
    </dd>                               
</dl>
```

After that is done, now is trivial to craft the insert statement just with:

```
$count=count($_POST);
$counter=0;
$query="INSERT INTO `notes` ( `group`, `data` ) VALUES ";
$resource=mysql_connect('host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    $key=mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    $value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $query.="('$key', '$value')";
    $query.=($counter<$count-1) ? ", " : ";";
    $counter++; //To know whether to put , or ; in SQL sentence
}
//echo $query; //To test it prior to insert for debugging purposes
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($resource);
```

And it should do it.

Edited to sanitize a bit $_POST data to avoid posible SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks but I still dont understand.  How can I take the array that is generate using dqhendricks answer, ex: `$b[1], $b[2]` and pull out the values I need from each of these arrays and get them all to `INSERT` ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe we can pick this up after I get some sleep =) but right now when I try that `foreach` I just see `('', ''), ('', '')` for the `VALUES`

Comment: @Zac it can be because of the mysql_real_escape_string, you can remove it, but you are open to SQL injections :)

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  I could make this work I guess but some of my values would be quite long and also this grabs my submit and puts it into the string so I have to get that out of there.  Here is a sample (I have not changed the values yet).

Comment: `VALUES (B_1, yes), (B_2, yes), (B_3, no), (B_4, no), (B_5, maybe), (B_6, maybe), (Submit, Submit);`

Comment: To avoid Submit to be submitted as an option, you must omit the name attribute of submit button, and this way it will be skipped in your POST. Something like `<input type='submit' value='Submit' />`

Comment: strange... I am using same way `<input type='submit' value='Submit' />`

Comment: I did test a form, and it seems it sends submit data when having name parameter. I omitted that parameter and no longer have the submit in my $_POST array :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8929/discussion-between-stormbyte-and-zac)

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to name your variables something a little more descriptive. Sure you know what they mean now, but a year from now it may take a minute to figure the code out.

Here is how you might consider looping through.

```
$groups = array(
   '3' => 'Coffee',
   '4' => 'Tea'
);

$b = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_post_vars; $i++) {
   $b[$i] = array(
      'Choices',
      $groups[$i],
      $_POST['B_' . $i]
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It looks like what I need but I am having troubles.  I added this and tried things like `print_r($b1)` and `echo($b1[1])` but get nothing.

Comment: @Zac $b is an array full of arrays. Use `print_r($b[1]);`.

Comment: Then you did not copy the above exactly, or you never set $number_of_post_vars. Do you understand what is happening in the above code?